Effective Bombieri-Lang conjecture
The Bombieri-Lang conjecture is the following well-known conjecture:
Let $X$ be a projective variety defined over a number field $K$. Suppose that $X$ is general type. Then $X(K)$, the set of $K$-rational points of $X$, is contained in a proper (Zariski) closed subset of $X$.
In the case of curves, $X$ is general type precisely when the genus of $X$ is at least $2$. In this case, Bombieri-Lang is a theorem: this is precisely the content of Mordell's conjecture, famously proved by Faltings in 1982.
In the curve case, there is a refinement of Mordell's conjecture/Faltings' theorem which is known as the uniform boundedness conjecture (UBC). It asserts:
Let $K$ be a number field and $g \geq 2$ an integer. Then there exists a positive integer $N(K,g)$ dependent only on $K$ and $g$ such that for all projective curves $C$ defined over $K$ of genus equal to $g$, one has $\# C(K) \leq N(K,g)$.
In particular, after fixing a genus and a base number field, the number of rational points on curves of genus $g$ defined over $K$ is uniformly bounded.
The uniform boundedness conjecture was famously proven conditionally by Caporaso, Harris, and Mazur, assuming precisely the general Bombieri-Lang conjecture.
My question is whether an analogue of UBC holds for higher dimensional varieties. Indeed, does the following hold?
Let $K$ be a number field, $n \geq 2$ an integer, and $d \geq n+1$ an integer. Do there exist positive integers $M(K,n,d), N(K, n, d)$ such that for all projective varieties $X$ defined over $K$ of dimension $n$ and degree $d$, the set of $K$-rational points $X(K)$ is contained in a union of at most $M(K,n,d)$ proper subvarieties of $X$, each of degree at most $N(K,n,d)$?

Maybe worth mentioning: there is a more precise version of this conjecture (on which, like the version you stated, opinions on the likelihood vary) that all but finitely many rational points fall inside all images of maps $A \to X$ from abelian varieties. This separated the problem into a geometric Lang conjecture (the images of such maps land in a proper subscheme) and an arithmetic parts (all but finitely many points land in this precise subscheme). You could ask for uniform versions of both; are you asking if these follow from the non-uniform versions à la CHM?

Also, given that you write $d \geq n+1$, are you thinking of the case where $X$ is a hypersurface in $\mathbf P^{n+1}$ in the general type range (as opposed to arbitrary $X$ of general type)? (I suppose that should be $d \geq n+3$ for the general type range, but ok.)

@R.vanDobbendeBruyn yes, perhaps some of the conditions are not the most natural. I am not aware of a numerical constant analogous to the genus for curves that captures the geometric condition of being general type. Surely, any uniform bounds applying to B-L would depend on such a number.

I would say 'uniform' means something about flat (or smooth) families over a connected (and finite type) base. No need to attach a numerical invariant to it, although I suppose one approximation is the Hilbert polynomial (with respect to a given ample line bundle), since this gives the connected components of the Hilbert scheme (which can be viewed as a crude version of a coarse moduli of polarised varieties).
